# How to make this kind of hover transition in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The page I just bumped into, has really amazing hover transition over Links, **in this case its images**

Page: http://other.wpengine.com/

I was wondering whether anyone has any idea how it is done. Is there any principle or specific way involved? Does someone know where I could look into it?

Comment: view the page source, it's all there view-source:http://other.wpengine.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is a tutorial of how to do it

https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/04/09/direction-aware-hover-effect-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.